# Can I exchange the position of the cancel/set buttons on Mobiscroll?

Tags: jquery-mobile, jquery-plugins, mobiscroll

I'm using Mobiscroll 2.0.3. The datepicker view gives ok button on the left and cancel button on the right. Can I exchange the position, like the cancel button on the left and set button on the right? Because I have ok/cancel buttons placed in the opposite way to Moviscroll on the site. Users would get confused if the button positions are different at each.

Answer (score 2):

You should be able to do that just using CSS and overriding the styles. I did it for the scroll-wheel view but the idea is the same (also note that that this was for mobiscroll 1.5.3 so the the markup and classes may have changed)

```
/* overide stlyes for mobi date/time picker */
.dwb-c 
{
    float:left;
     margin-bottom:12px;
}

.dwb-s 
{
    float:right;
    margin-bottom:12px;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I know it's late but if someone try to google it, just try this https://docs.mobiscroll.com/jquery/datetime#opt-buttons

You can set an array of buttons to display and you can use string names if you wanna show default buttons. So if you wanna change direction just set buttons like this:

```
buttons: ["cancel", "set"]
```